# Next.JS dynamic route is not working for /somefolder/new

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, prisma, next.js13

I have a next.JS project, and I am using Prisma with Mongodb, and there is dynamic routes in it, basically when we have **[somefolder]/page.tsx** and then in the browser we hit **https://localhost/somefolder/new**, it should go to the page with an empty form, but it is not working, however it is working if I go to **https://localhost/somefolder/someId**, I know that I can create something like **/[somefolder]/new/page.tsx**, but I want **https://localhost/somefolder/new** and **[somefolder]/page.tsx**  to work
and I am getting this error when going to **https://localhost/somefolder/new**

[image]

my page.tsx in somefolder looks like:

```js
import { ProductForm } from "@/components/product-form";
import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";

const ProductPage = async ({ params }: { params: { productId: string } }) => {
  const product = await prismadb.product.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: params.productId,
    },
  });

  return (
    <div className="w-full p-10 m-10">
      <ProductForm initialData={product} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductPage;
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that MongodDB with Prisma is not supporting it, I switched to mySQL and it works

Answer (score 3):

When accessing `https://localhost/somefolder/<productId>`, `params.productId` will be assigned the value of `<productId>`.

In the case of accessing `https://localhost/somefolder/someId`, `params.productId` would have the value `someId`, which I assume would be an id of some item inside of your Mongodb, so it works fine.

When accessing `https://localhost/somefolder/new`, `params.productId` would have the value `new` which is an invalid id to look for inside your db, hence the error you get.

To handle this issue, one solution would be to create a special page to handle that specific path, located at `app/(dashboard)/(routes)/products/[productId]/new/page.tsx`. This way whenever `new` is in the URL, the page would take precedence over the dynamic path.